# How Firebase C++ SDK allocate memory for DatabaseReference and DatabaseSnapshot?

Tags: android, c++, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, sdk

Today we use Firebase C++ SDK and I like to improve the way we load data from Firebase to app Entity classes, today we loop over DatabaseSnapshot and populate Entity classes to be used in Android APP, but I think that this give us a slow process and too much data movement from Firebase to our APP.

The algorithm used today is:

1. set "loadData" value in /command/categories
2. listen the value change to "finished" in /command/categories
3. When finished the data arrives in /categories
4. Then we loop /categories snapshot and construct Entities from those values

I think this algorithm can be improved in terms of memory consumption, but to be sure I need to know how Firebase C++ SDK allocates memory.

My toughts is that DatabaseReference is more fast to read and update values than DatabaseSnapshot, as I understand DatabaseSnapshot is a copy of data and DatabaseReference is a reference for that data, then if I change my Entity classes to use DatabaseReference directly instead of just get from Snapshot and set on Entity I can improve my app memory consumption, then I like to change my app entity to have a DatabaseReference and each time I use set/get I use that DatabaseReference instead to set/get in class local variables.

Anyone know about better ways to do that?

TIA
Clóvis

Comment: It sounds like you want to read the value directly from `DatabaseReference`, which is like a pointer to the value, but not actually the value itself.  When you read `DatabaseReference`, it returns a `DatabaseSnapshot` which is the value at a particular point in time.

Comment: It sounds like you are grabbing an entire tree from the root and then processing the sub-children.  A faster method would to be to add a [onChildAdded](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/cpp/retrieve-data#child-callbacks) listener which will fire once for each child.  Then you could process each child in order consuming on the memory needed to process that single child.  Another approach is to use a `Query` to [paginate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/cpp/retrieve-data#filtering_data) your requests so that you only process 5 or so children at a time.

Comment: Yes, we created a kind of singleton of the device data to populate on demand based on commands we set on database, then that is  a way of pagination we used without using firebase queries, we have a bunch of segmented databases.

Comment: today if we export a JSON from that segmented database it only consumes 1.1MB its already very small and segmented, but I like to avoid traversal things, like using onChildAdded too. Because as command got finished we already know that all data is there, then I like to just take the data screen needs, like we can do in webapp with javascript and JSON bindings.

Comment: A DatabaseReference is mostly just a logical construct that holds a path to remote DB data (and local cached content). Until you establish a listener of some sort, it doesn't download or parse anything. What you're probably wanting here is to just do a [GET request](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api) on the path and to parse the data on your own so you can minimize the footprint. But it's unlikely you'll get any significant gains over the onChildAdded constructs.